# track filechanges on shared hosting account

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

So I like to keep track of added files but also edited files.

```
find /home/user/public_html -type f -mtime -6 ! -path '*/exclude1*' ! -path '*/exclude2/etc*' -exec ls -ls {} \; | mail -e -s "File Monitor Report" user@user.com
```

This does excactly what i need but i need it to add what changed (E edited N new D deleted) or something like this.

Now this is been asked loads of time and the answer is always the same:
fswatch inotify auditd or someother package. this is not an option due to it being a cpanel shared hosting server i do not have that access.

So I am looking for the most simple way to do this or that comes close to it.

git is available but asfaik i know you need to make a repository commit changes etc it does not scan a folder for them. Also it needs to be scriptable

So in short just need a as simple possible script to mail the changes on a daily base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're literally asking for a version control system, like Git.

You could roll your own, by making a cronjob that copies all files to a "prev" directory and mails you a `diff -r`, but that's really something that a VCS already does more efficiently and usually withess effort, so you might as well use that.

> git is available but asfaik i know you need to make a repository commit changes etc it does not scan a folder for them.

It does if you ask it to. That's literally one of the core features of any version control system: telling you what changed between commits, as well as telling you what changed since last commit (i.e. what hasn't been committed yet).

So if you have a repository in public_html, you just do `git status` or `git diff` to see the changes. In particular, `--name-status` would show you a list of A(dded)/M(odified)/D(eleted) files like you're asking. The same can be applied to commands that show changes between commits.

> Also it needs to be scriptable

Every version control system is scriptable. Git in particular is so scriptable that many of its user-facing commands used to be (and sometimes still are) just shell scripts around low-level commands.

Most other version control systems are also scriptable *at least* to the point of making a commit and showing you a change summary (the Add/Mod/Del output that you're asking for is often actually the default output of e.g. a `hg status` or `svn status`).

Your cronjob would basically be:

```bash
cd ~user/public_html
git add --all
git commit -m "Daily snapshot"
# Output the changes for cronmail
git show --name-status
# ...and output the whole diff as well.
git show --stat
```

Comment: call me stupid but this to the point and short explanation got me to understand how to use git locally i assumed it always has to upload to git hub to cross referance the files.